# Applying a list of functions to a list of arguments using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there a function in Ramda to apply a list of functions to a list of arguments similar to `juxt()` but where each function only gets supplied with the argument at the corresponding index in the list of arguments? Something similar to:

```js
pipe(zip, map(([a, b]) => a(b)))([func1, func2], ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use R.zipWith which creates a new list out of the two supplied by applying the function to each equally-positioned pair in the lists.

You can also replace the callback with R.call, which invokes the first argument, and passes the rest as it's parameters.

```js
const { zipWith, call } = R;

const fn = zipWith(call);

const func1 = R.add(1);
const func2 = R.add(2);

const result = fn([func1, func2], [1, 2]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I've never been a fan of `call` but using `zipWith` is definitely the right way of doing it IMHO.

Comment: R.call is a bit confusing, but it mirrors the native call. do you have other reasons not to use it?

Comment: None. Pure personal taste. I'd have written `zipWith((a, b) => a(b))` so as to match the `map(…)` above and make things _slightly_ more obvious (one thing less to lookup in the docs) but I'm just nitpicking really.